# Out of Memory exception java

Tags: java

I got this error message when trying to run a  school project. If it's helpful I need to write a code that takes in strings from the user and counts the amount of #'s they enter.

Here is my project code:

```
    package edu.bsu.cs121.albeaver;

    import java.util.*;

    public class HashTagCounter {
        public static void main(String args[]){
            boolean go = true;
            System.out.println("Please tweet your tweets: ");
            Scanner twitterInput = new Scanner(System.in);

            String tweet = twitterInput.next();
            ArrayList<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();


            while(go == true){
                tweets.add(tweet);
                if(tweet == "done"){
                    go = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(tweets);
            twitterInput.close();
        }

    }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
    at edu.bsu.cs121.albeaver.HashTagCounter.main(HashTagCounter.java:16)
```

I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: `tweet == "done"` is never true, because in Java, `==` compares strings by their reference, not their value.  Also, you have to read the next tweet *within the loop.*

Comment: use equals instead of "==" while your compare two Strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping forever (even after correcting the `==` error) because you always check the same tweet. This would probably work better:

```
List<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();

while (true) {
    String tweet = twitterInput.next();
    if ("done".equals(tweet)) break;
    tweets.add(tweet);
}
```

Comment: yeah, he's adding the same string forever, so heap space is depleted

Answer (score 1):

You are never setting `go` to `true` because the `String` comparison never succeeds. **Don't compare strings with `==`. Use the `equals()` method instead**. So change:

```
if(tweet == "done"){
```

to:

```
if(tweet.equals("done")){
```

However, this won't solve your problem entirely. You also need to update the `tweet` variable inside of the loop, otherwise you'll always be comparing against the same `String`. See assylias' answer for a code example.

Comment: @MartinDinov if tweet is not "done" when entering the loop, it will be an infinite loop (even after your correction).

Answer (score 1):

```
        while(go == true){
            tweets.add(tweet);
            if(tweet.equals("done")) { // this line should be changed
                go = false;
            }
        }
```

In your case, `tweet == "done"` is never going to execute, and hence the while loop gets to infinite loop. This causes `Null Pointer Exception`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you first read the tweet and then initiate a while cycle, that adds the same tweet over and over again, until you run out of memory. Add

```
System.out.println(tweets.size());
```

behind

```
tweets.add(tweet);
```

to get a better grasp of what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

There are several items you should take from this learning experience:

1. There is a difference between comparing objects (to see if they are the same object) and comparing the String value of objects. For string comparison, you will usually want to use the form `String1.equalsIgnoreCase(String2)` (If case matters, then one uses String1.equals(String2).)
2. For loops that involve getting input from somewhere you may want to use the form

   ```
   line = [get input]
   while (!line.equealsIgnoreCase([end string]) {
       [ do work on line ]
       line = [get input]
   }
   ```